# User profile boxes are shrunk when mod info overflows beyond fixed height subheader on profile pages

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, moderator-tools

The mod-only info for user profile pages overflows beyond the fixed header, causing the profile boxes below to shrink left:

[image]

I recommend shortening the link text "Account Info" to just "Info", which would immediately resolve this issue:

[image]

Comment: given how the rep graph looks like, I'm guessing the image is based on Jon Skeet's profile? :P